# How do I list posts from the same category in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I’d like to list a fixed number of recent posts having the same category as the current post. This is what I have arrived at:

```
{% for category_name in page.categories limit:1 %}
    <h2>Other articles in {{ category_name }}</h2>
    <ul>
        <!-- now what? -->
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I know about `site.categories`, but I don’t know how to subscript the dictionary. Obviously, `site.categories.category_name` is taken literally, looking for a category named “category_name”.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
{% for post in site.categories[category_name] %}
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not work, the code bellow works please update your code

Answer (score 16):

Based on the [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables), indexing (i.e., `[category_name]`) is no longer the correct answer. Now (since at least Jekyll v2), given a category name `FOO`, the correct way to list all posts of that category is

```
{% for post in site.categories.FOO %}
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

To note, I recently ran into this issue, my configuration is

```
$ jekyll -v
jekyll 2.0.3
```

Comment: But `category_name` is a variable, whereas `FOO` is a literal, so how could this work?

Comment: works for tags too; e.g. `site.tags.ruby` gives you a list of all posts tagged 'ruby'

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
{% for post in site.categories.FOO %}
 + [{{ post.title }}]({{ page.url }})
{% endfor %}
```