# How to list all posts without a category in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

How does one list all the posts in a Jekyll blog that do not have a specified category?

How to list all *in* a given category is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723426/how-do-i-list-posts-from-the-same-category-in-jekyll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.categories contains 'postcategory' %}
    <h1>Do nothing</h1>
  {% else %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That only works for a display perspective but no if you want to do something like display the last 3 posts without categories :(

Comment: @Clawfire but this answers the question that is : How does one list all the posts in a Jekyll blog that do not have a specified category?
Comments are not made to ask questions.